# How to draw a polyline on video frames using opencv?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I have a x and y co ordinates of 50 frames in a video. i am trying to draw a polyline for these frames. instead of drawing a line for these co ordinates, i am just getting a single dot in one fixed place like this.(or am i using wrong thing(polyline) to solve this problem?)

desired output:

points is my numpy array having x,y co ordinates for these 50 frames:

```
[[400 341]
 [401 345]
 [400 344]
 [400 340]
 [401 344].........]
```

here is my code for drawing polyline:

```
idx =0
#capture video
vs = cv2.VideoCapture(video_path)

#initialsing tracker
tracker= cv2.TrackerCSRT_create

#loop over frames

while True:

# grab the current frame, 
frame = vs.read()

# check to see if we have reached the end of the stream
if frame is None:
    break

# frame dimensions
(H, W) = frame.shape[:2]
```

**this is the part for drawing, rest of the code i didnt include is just about initialising the object tracking algorithm**

```
 # check to see if the tracking was a success
  if success:
        (x, y, w, h) = [int(v) for v in box]
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x + w, y + h),
            (0, 255, 0), 2) 
        cv2.line(frame, (x + w // 2, y), (x + w // 2, y + h), (0, 0,255), 2)

        center = (x + w // 2, y + h // 2)
        radius = 2
        cv2.circle(frame, center, radius, (255, 255, 0), 2)

    #if frame number is in in range (600-650) draw polyline with the co ordinates stored in points
    if idx in range(600, 650):
           cv2.polylines(frame, np.int32([points]), isClosed=True, color=(0,0, 255), thickness=2)
idx=idx+1
```

Can someone tell me how to do it?

Comment: what is `d3`? Can you create a [mcve] with code that runs?

Comment: Polyline returns a new image - so you should store the new frames

Comment: @Stefan you are mistaken. it returns the input array (first parameter), while also modifying it. the return value can be safely ignored because it's identical to what was passed in.

Comment: @alkasm i mistakened d3 with points. i have changed it now. it is my numpay array of co ordinates for these frames. Can you check the question now?

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz can u help me figure out. i have edited the question

Comment: *minimal* reproducible example. most of that code has nothing to do with drawing. reduce the code to the minimum required to reproduce the issue.

Comment: i have edited again, but thats most of it what's required. i have added the drawing part. KIndly check @ChristophRackwitz

Comment: how about [`drawContours()`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.2/d4/d73/tutorial_py_contours_begin.html) ?

Comment: @GeorgeProfenza i dont think that would work..it should consider co ordinates and i dont have anything to specify the edge for drawing

Comment: Ok, I'm getting confused, thought you had a contour/polygon to draw. 
Re-reading your question you simply want to draw a dot in a fixed place ? 
If so, it should be easy with [`ellipse()`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.2/d6/d6e/group__imgproc__draw.html#ga28b2267d35786f5f890ca167236cbc69). You know your dot location, specify the size of the dot and that's should be it

Comment: @GeorgeProfenza no I want to draw lines itself but I didnt understand how u were suggesting to do it with drawcontours( ). I have added the desired ouput image also in the question.Please have a look.

Comment: @GeorgeProfenza right now I am getting a dot at fixed place but i want to draw a line connecting these 50 co ordinates

Comment: @katan did my answer bellow help ?

Comment: @GeorgeProfenza thanks a lot for the effort mate! unfortunately it still plots a dot in a fixed place in that range

Comment: Double check the data as well...the short snippet you posted has a motion range of max 4-5 pixels (e.g. x movement between 400 and 401, y movement between 340 and 345). It might help if you post the whole 50 points you're trying to draw ? (if it's too long for stackoverflow you could use something like pastebin and share a link). it will be much easier for others if you can simply copy/paste the array in python and test, right ? :)

Comment: https://pastebin.com/sQwgNtff @GeorgeProfenza Please refer this link, i have uploaded the data there :)

Comment: @ketan As I suspected: the lines are drawn correctly, the points are clustered in a small blob area. See the update to my answer bellow. If it is the solution to the polylines drawing problem please mark it as such with the green checkbox. (btw, notice how I formatted the snippet: in the future please make it easy for others to easily copy/paste use your data with no formatting required (e.g. `print(points.tolist())` instead just `print(points)`)

Answer (score 1):

The image you posted recently is a lot clearer.

Based on this snippet:

```
[[400 341]
 [401 345]
 [400 344]
 [400 340]
 [401 344].........]
```

the assumption is the 50 points you want to draw are numpy int32 array with shape `(50, 2)` stored as the variable named `points`.

If so, you want to reshape it as mentioned above and use the `False` argument in `polylines()` to draw the line path (instead of a closed polygon):

```
cv2.polylines(frame, [points], isClosed=False, color=(0,0, 255), thickness=2)
```

(We're using `[points]` instead of `points` because points are the data for a single poly line while `cv2.polylines()` can draw multiple poly lines (e.g. `cv.polylines(frame, [points1, points2, ...], etc.)`)

**Update**

Based on your comment I see **all** the points are moving in a very narrow regions. While the `cv2.polyline` drawing may work because of your values it will look a tiny blob when you're expecting a large path. The poly line drawing use though.

Here's a demo of your data with two poly lines drawn: in green is your original data, in red is your data offset to the top left corner and scaled up by a factor of **60**:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

points = np.array([[400, 341],
 [401, 345],
 [400, 344],
 [400, 340],
 [401, 344],
 [401, 346],
 [401, 344],
 [402, 345],
 [398, 346],
 [399, 345],
 [400, 343],
 [399, 343],
 [399, 344],
 [399, 344],
 [402, 345],
 [398, 343],
 [399, 344],
 [400, 342],
 [398, 342],
 [399, 343],
 [400, 342],
 [399, 343],
 [402, 344],
 [398, 344],
 [399, 343],
 [400, 343],
 [400, 343],
 [401, 342],
 [401, 343],
 [401, 343],
 [398, 343],
 [399, 342],
 [400, 341],
 [399, 342],
 [400, 342],
 [399, 341],
 [399, 341],
 [400, 341],
 [399, 342],
 [402, 341],
 [398, 341],
 [399, 342],
 [401, 343],
 [401, 342],
 [401, 342],
 [398, 342],
 [399, 344],
 [400, 342],
 [399, 345],
 [397, 342]], dtype=np.int32)

# use this blank image as a placeholder for your camera image
frame = np.zeros((480, 640, 3), dtype=np.uint8)

# draw original polylines
cv2.polylines(frame, [points], isClosed=False, color=(0, 192, 0), thickness=1)
cv2.putText(frame,"original data", tuple(points.min(axis = 0) + [3, -6]), 0, 0.75, (255, 255, 255))

# quick'n'dirty offset and scale points (60 times !!!) for visualisation purposes
cv2.polylines(frame, [((points - points.min(axis = 0)) * 60)], isClosed=False, color=(0, 0, 192), thickness=2)
cv2.putText(frame,"scaled data", (9, 21), 0, 0.75, (255, 255, 255))

# preview
cv2.imshow('polylines debug demo', frame)
```

[image: red polylines displaying data scaled by a factor of 60 and a small green blob displaying the original data]

Feel free to tinker with the data in this [colab notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/12obZs11xL-uGHoZg6DTVLct32Zt9D6GL?usp=sharing)

Now why the tracked points are a small blob is a different problem / question altogether related potentially to the data and how tracking is done: a great candidate for another post perhaps.